# Can't build application with boost semaphores

Tags: c++, boost

So I'm trying to implement a blocking queue using boost, but this thing is impossible to compile...

```
template<class T>
class BlockingQueue {
private:
    std::queue<T> blockedQueue;
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore *counter;

public:
    BlockingQueue(){
        counter = new boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore(0);
    }
    virtual ~BlockingQueue(){
        delete counter;
    }

    /**
     * puts blockingly an element to the queue
     */
    void put(T element) {
        this->blockedQueue.push(element);
        this->counter->post();
    }

    /**
     * blocingly reads an element fromt he queue
     */
    T* get(){
        this->counter->wait();
        T* result = &this->blockedQueue.front();
        this->blockedQueue.pop();
        return result;
    }

};
```

then for the testing purposes I only added in my main function

```
BlockingQueue<int>i;
    i.get();
```

still, when I try to compile it, I get the follwing error:

> ./src/Test.o: In function
>   `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::semaphore_init(sem_t*, unsigned
>   int)':
>   /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/semaphore_wrapper.hpp:129:
>   undefined reference to`sem_init' ./src/Test.o: In function
>   `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::semaphore_destroy(sem_t*)':
>   /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/semaphore_wrapper.hpp:140:
>   undefined reference to`sem_destroy' ./src/Test.o: In function
>   `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::semaphore_wait(sem_t*)':
>   /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/semaphore_wrapper.hpp:156:
>   undefined reference to`sem_wait'

for compiling I used "g++ -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -pthread -lrt"
so... what did I do wrong?

Comment: what? Do I need to build it separately? I only installed it from repo with "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev". Do I need to do anything else with it before usage?

Comment: Looking again at the missing references, it looks like it might be a pthread issue. Maybe try -lpthread?

Comment: @KamilMilkaJanowski apt-get install libboost-all-dev is enough. The package contains the pre-built library and headers, you don't need to build it.

Answer (score 1):

The interprocess library specifically mentions this in its [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html#interprocess.intro.introduction_building_interprocess)

> In POSIX systems, Boost.Interprocess uses pthread system calls to
>   implement classes like mutexes, condition variables, etc... In some
>   operating systems, these POSIX calls are implemented in separate
>   libraries that are not automatically linked by the compiler. For
>   example, in some Linux systems POSIX pthread functions are implemented
>   in librt.a library, so you might need to add that library when linking
>   an executable or shared library that uses Boost.Interprocess. If you
>   obtain linking errors related to those pthread functions, please
>   revise your system's documentation to know which library implements
>   them.

On Linux, [link with `-pthread`.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_destroy.3.html)